# View not reloading when @Published property is updated SwiftUI iOS15

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine

I am trying to maintain an MVVM structure, and I've run into this issue where the view will show the value of the @Published variable one behind.  The updated value will only be shown in View after I close the app and reopen it.  The @Published variable `remindersCount` is not triggering the reload of my view.

I've spent days attempting different things and reading stack overflow and other forums and it seems this should work but obviously, I am doing something wrong.  If someone could point me in the right direction, I would really appreciate it.  Thank you.

**The ViewModel has 2 published variables:
**

```
class ReminderViewModel: ObservableObject {
   @Published private(set) var reminders: [ReminderModel] = []
   @Published private(set) var remindersCount: Int = 0

    init(dataService: any ReminderDataServiceProtocol) {
        self.dataService = dataService
        getReminders()
        getRemindersCount()
    }
```

The `reminders` and `remindersCount` variables are updated like so:

```
    func getReminders() {
        dataService.get()
            .sink { error in
                fatalError("\(error)")
            } receiveValue: { reminders in
                self.reminders = reminders
            }
            .store(in: &cancellables)
    }

    func getRemindersCount() {
        $reminders
            .map { (_: [ReminderModel]) -> Int in
                return self.reminders.count
            }
            .sink(receiveValue: { [weak self] count in
                self?.remindersCount = count
            })
            .store(in: &cancellables)
    }
```

After running user interactions through some logic, the Reminders database gets updated with this function, which lives in another ViewModel:

```
for time in randomTimes {
    let idNotification = UUID().uuidString
        let newReminder: ReminderModel = ReminderModel(idNotification: idNotification, random:             true, date: time)
            reminderVM.saveReminder(reminder: newReminder)
            notificationMgr.scheduleNotification(identifier: idNotification, date: time)
}
```

**Implementation of a simple functionality to showcase the issue **

First Scenario: I expected the `reminderVM.remindersCount` to update and trigger the reload, but it is always one behind.  I have to close the app and reopen it to have the the view with the updated count data

```
struct PreferencesView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject private var reminderVM: ReminderViewModel

    var body: some View {

        NavigationView {
            Text("NUMBER OF REMINDERS: \(reminderVM.remindersCount)")
        }
    }
}
```

Second Scenario: Since that didn't work, I attempted to "force" an update by adding a button for testing purposes.  Still encountered the same issue.

```
struct PreferencesView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject private var reminderVM: ReminderViewModel

    var body: some View {

        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Button("reload") {
                    reminderVM.getRemindersCount()
                }
                Text("NUMBER OF REMINDERS: \(reminderVM.remindersCount)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#################################################################
MINIMAL REPRODUCIBLE EXAMPLE
#################################################################

```
import SwiftUI
import Foundation
import Combine
import CoreData

struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject private var reminderVM: ReminderViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            VStack (){
                Button("Add a reminder") {
                    let newReminder: ReminderModel = ReminderModel(idNotification: UUID().uuidString, random: true, date: Date.now)
                    reminderVM.saveReminder(reminder: newReminder)
                }
                .buttonStyle(.bordered)
                Text("NUMBER OF REMINDERS: \(reminderVM.remindersCount)")
                Button("Update") {
                    print("button pressed")
                    reminderVM.getRemindersCount()
                }
                .buttonStyle(.bordered)
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}


class ReminderViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    private let dataService: ReminderDataService
    
    private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    @Published private(set) var reminders: [ReminderModel] = []
    @Published private(set) var remindersCount: Int = 0
    
    init(dataService: ReminderDataService) {
        self.dataService = dataService
        getReminders()
        getRemindersCount()
    }
    
    func saveReminder(reminder: ReminderModel) {
        dataService.add(reminder)
    }
    
    func getReminders() {
        dataService.get()
            .sink { error in
                fatalError("\(error)")
            } receiveValue: { reminders in
                self.reminders = reminders
            }
            .store(in: &cancellables)
    }
    
    func getRemindersCount() {
        $reminders
            .map { (_: [ReminderModel]) -> Int in
                return self.reminders.count
            }
            .sink(receiveValue: { [weak self] count in
                self?.remindersCount = count
            })
            .store(in: &cancellables)
    }
    
}


class ReminderDataService: ObservableObject {
    @Published private var reminderEntities: [Reminder] = []

    private let persistenceController: PersistenceController
    private let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<Reminder>(entityName: "Reminder")
    
    
    init(persistenceController: PersistenceController) {
        self.persistenceController = persistenceController
        fetch()
    }
    
    func get() -> AnyPublisher<[ReminderModel], Error> {
        $reminderEntities.tryMap { reminders in
            reminders.map {reminder in
                ReminderModel(reminder: reminder)
            }
        }
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
    
    func add(_ reminder: ReminderModel) {
        let reminderEntity = Reminder(context: persistenceController.container.viewContext)
        reminderEntity.id = reminder.id
        reminderEntity.idNotification = reminder.idNotification
        reminderEntity.random = reminder.random
        reminderEntity.date = reminder.date
        saveContext()
    }
    
    // MARK: Private functions
    private func fetch() {
        do {
            fetchRequest.predicate = nil
            reminderEntities = try persistenceController.container.viewContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
        } catch let error {
            print("Error: Unable to fetch core data using data services \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
    
    private func saveContext() {
        do {
            try persistenceController.container.viewContext.save()
        } catch let error{
            print("Error saving reminders in Core Data: \(error)")
        }
        fetch()
    }
}


class PersistenceController: ObservableObject {

    static let shared = PersistenceController()
        
    let container: NSPersistentContainer
    
    init() {
        container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "Model")
        container.loadPersistentStores { description, error in
            if let error = error {
                print("Core Data failed to load: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
    }
}


struct ReminderModel: Hashable, Identifiable, Codable {
    var id = UUID()
    var idNotification: String
    var random: Bool
    var date: Date
}


extension ReminderModel {
    init(reminder: Reminder) {
        id = reminder.id ?? UUID()
        idNotification = reminder.idNotification ?? ""
        random = reminder.random
        date = reminder.date ?? Date.now
    }
}
```

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct MRE_App: App {
    
    @StateObject private var reminderVM = ReminderViewModel(dataService: ReminderDataService(persistenceController: (PersistenceController.shared)))
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environmentObject(reminderVM)
            
        }
    }
}
```

**Core Data**

Entity: Reminder

| Attribute. | Type |
| --- | --- |
| date | Date |
| id | UUID |
| idNotification | String |
| random | Boolean |

Comment: Can you include a [mre]? You have most of it here, but not enough to run. Also, why bother having a separate property for the count? Why not just `reminders.count`?

Comment: The `getRemindersCount()` does not make any force update - it just creates a subscription. Did you try to debug and make sure that the `receiveValue` in `getReminders()` returns correct reminders with the right count?

Comment: @jnpdx, I believe that my attempt of using the Published wrapper for reminders count was because reminders.count wasn't updating, and I thought this might be a solution.  In any case, posted all the code necessary to run. Thanks!

Comment: You only call `fetch` once on init and then never update `reminderEntities`. Have you considered just using the standard SwiftUI property wrappers for interfacing with CoreData?

Comment: the saveContext() calls fetch().  shouldn't that update the reminderEntities.  To your question... yes, I guess that is an option as well... just trying to figure this out

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `self.reminders` because at the moment when a subscription gets new value, the property still have old value.

So when set new value to a `@Published` property the logic is next:

1. all subscribers get new value
2. underlying value of the property updated with the new value

```swift
func getRemindersCount() {
    $reminders
        .map { (newReminders: [ReminderModel]) -> Int in // <-- HERE
            return newReminders.count
        }
        .sink(receiveValue: { [weak self] count in
            self?.remindersCount = count
        })
        .store(in: &cancellables)
}
```

Or a short version with the same result:

```swift
func getRemindersCount() {
    $reminders
        .map(\.count)
        .assign(to: &$remindersCount)
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Andrew.. Good to know how the value gets propagated.  I tested out both of your suggestions and I am still encountering the same behavior..

Comment: I've created a sample project with your code and it works after my update.. Ok, then please provide a fully work example with the issue which I and others can check.

Comment: Andrew and @jnpdx, I isolated the code of interest and updated my question with it.  I am pretty new at this and I am trying to work with MVVM pattern, so I am sorry if I "over coded" for things that might be more simple using wrappers in swift...   the pattern is view-> view model -> service -> core data (so in the future I might change persistence framework).

Comment: Hey @trilogy , I have tested the new code you have shared. The code has issue you have described. But when I use code from my answer (`getRemindersCount`) it works good. You can see it on attached gif. Please double check.

Comment: Hi Andrew.  I figured out what was happening.  The MRE that I published has a simplification that did not reflect the actual issue.  Since I posted the VM and view in the same file, they both had access to the Environmental Objects.  But in my code the VM is a swift file with no access to the EO wrapper.  The way I had implemented it, I believe, had different instances running, one for the VM and another for the View. That is why it wasn't updating.. I implemented this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59491675/swiftui-how-to-pass-environmentobject-into-view-model, & it is working for now.

Comment: Hi @trilogy, thank you for sharing the details about the fix. I'm glad you fix it :)

Answer (score -2):

In SwiftUI the View struct is the view model already so you can just remove the ReminderViewModel class and do:

```
@State var reminders: [ReminderModel] = []

var remindersCount: Int {
    reminders.count
}
```

Then just make a func to return reminders and save it in the state. Best is an async func called from .task. Even better put the func in an EnvironmentKey so you can mock it in previews.